# Nodejs error when trying to use processes object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

When I'm trying to use the process object in TypeScript, I get an error when running `tsc foo.ts`

in foo.ts, I try to use the process object:

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

These are the error messages I'm getting:

```
node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:680:34 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

680             : F extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer T
                                     ~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:681:17 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

681                 ? T
                    ~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:682:17 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

682                 : unknown,
                    ~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:685:34 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

685             : F extends abstract new (...args: infer Y) => any
                                     ~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:686:17 - error TS1005: ':' expected.


...
...
                         ~


Found 19 errors.
```

I'm trying to use the process object to take the command line arguments from the user, and then I ran into this problem. Besides the process objects, are there any other betterways of getting the arguments?

How do I fix this error? I'm very new to nodejs and typescript, it would be great if someone can link the documetation for this.

I tryed to configure the tsconfig.json, but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the version of `"typescript"` in package.json? And what do you get by running `npx tsc --version`?

Comment: @qrsngky Version 5.0.2

Comment: What about the result of `tsc --version` ?

Comment: @qrsngky bash: /usr/bin/tsc: No such file or directory
but i'm pretty sure typescript package is installed.

Comment: I did some research on npm and am wondering if it's a good practice to run npm as root since this is just a permission issue. Running tsc as root solves the problem, but is there any other better ways of doing this?